# Salesforce Email Service Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex-code, apex

Maybe I've been staring at this for too long.

I have a simple inbound email service that stores a lead and sends a response email.  My unit test shows 0% coverage even though my debug statements hit and my system assert passes. What am I doing wrong?

Email Service:

```
global class sampleConEmailToLead implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, 
                                                       Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){
    // create inbound response
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

    //boolean to attach note
    Boolean attachNote = false;
    // query leads to see if lead exist
    List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Id, Name, Email
        FROM Lead
        WHERE Email = :email.fromAddress];

    // if lead doesnt exist in system create lead
    if (leads.size() == 0) {
        Lead newLead = new Lead(Email = email.fromAddress, 
        LastName = 'From SampleCon', 
        Company = 'From SampleCon');

        // insert lead
        insert newLead;   
        leads.add(newLead);

        attachNote = true; 
    } else if (leads.size() == 1){
        attachNote = true;

    } else {
        System.debug('Duplicate Exist... not adding: ' + leads );    
    }

    if(attachNote == true){
        createNote(leads[0].id, email.subject, email.plaintextbody);
    }
    // set result to true or emails will bounce back 
    result.success = true;
    //send response email
    if(leads.size() > 0){
        sendResponseEmail(email.fromAddress, leads[0].id);
    }
    // le fin
    return result;
  }

    private void createNote(ID leadID, String subject, String body){
        system.debug('### LeadID : ' + leadID);
        system.debug('### Subject : ' + subject);
        system.debug('### Body : ' + body);
        note newNote = new note();
        newNote.parentId = LeadID;
        newNote.title = subject;
        newNote.body = body;

        try{
            insert newNote;
        } 
        catch(exception e){
            system.debug('#### Error: ' + e);
        }

    }

    private void sendResponseEmail(String email, ID leadID){
        final String template = 'Test Template';
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        ID templateId = [select id from EmailTemplate where Name = :template].id;
        system.debug('### templateID : ' + templateID);


        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        message.setTemplateId(templateId);
        message.setTargetObjectId(LeadId);
        //message.setWhatId(uc.Id);

        message.setToAddresses(new String[] {email});
        messages.add(message);

        Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
        system.debug('#### message : ' + message);

    }
}
```

and the unit test:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class sampleConEmailToLead_Test{
    static testMethod void testInboundEmail(){
       // create a new email and envelope object
        Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
        Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();

        email.plainTextBody = 'teset';
        email.fromAddress = 'test@test.com';
        email.subject = 'Test Lead';

        sampleConEmailToLead edr = new sampleConEmailToLead();
        edr.handleInboundEmail(email,env); 

        Test.startTest();
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = edr.handleInboundEmail(email, env);
        System.assertEquals(result.success, true);
        Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you running Asynchronously [Test -> Always Run Asynchronously].  That is what you need to do to get line counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your test configuration to run Asynchronously.

1) Select the Test menu.
2) Select "Always Run Asynchronously" from the drop-down.
3) Re-run your test, Overall Code Coverage will update and so will the red/blue color coding on the Class in the dev console.

Comment: Thank you! 97% coverage when selected.  It was driving me crazy!